# Hosting specific Nextjs page on a custom domain

Tags: next.js, domain-name

Let's say I have a next js app and a page like this. `nextapp.com/content3`

So, what I want to achieve is that somehow map the domain name `userdomain.com` to my Nextjs page `nextapp.com/content3`.

So, In the end when someone enters `userdomain.com` in their browser my page i.e. `nextapp.com/content3` should be rendered on it.

No redirects, I need to be on userdomain.com but use my Nextjs page content.

Comment: fetch contents from the URL ``nextapp.com/content3`` and render it on your domain part using ay language, PHP or Node or anything of your choice.. At the DNS level it's not possible I guess to create A CNAME record to point at a non root domain URL, if I am not wrong

Comment: So you're suggesting tp create a separate app or js file to fetch and display the content on `userdomain.com`, Right ?

Comment: yes, kinda........